How do warps map onto SM sub-partitions in a GPU?

Above is a diagram of the A100 SM. It shows that the SM is partitioned into four groups of cores, each of which executes 32-thread warps.
At any given time, how many warps are running on each sub-partition? One or multiple?
Suppose each thread in a warp must add two 64-bit floating point numbers. Since the sub-partition only has 8 FP64 units, we can't do 32 FP64 ops in one clock cycle. What happens in this case? Do the 32 FP64 ops execute in groups of 8 over 4 clock cycles? Can the INT32 and FP32 units execute threads from other warps (or the same warp) while this happens?
If you could please suggest references (books, papers, articles, etc) to better understand this I would appreciate it.

It requires reading between the lines in the volta whitepaper, the tuning guide (also the others for comparison) and the reverse engineering papers. I don't have a definite answer but it sounds like 32 bit instructions are issued over two cycles and 64 bit over 4 cycles. The warp scheduler supports double-issue so a float and an int or load instruction can be issued in the same cycle.

But a single warp scheduler can only ever issue instructions from a single warp per cycle. And if the warp is divergent, only one branch can execute per cycle. No mixing of an int instruction in branch A with a float instruction in branch B

An SM is a single physical core. But - AFAIK,  NVIDIA doesn't commit to a description what really, physically, happens within an SM and how it's actually structured. These diagrams are suggested conceptual models of the SM, not necessarily a physical diagram of it. You can't assume that a warp executes on a quarter of the diagram.

@Homer512 Where does it say double-issue?

@Sebastian It doesn't really say that, so it might be wrong. The whitepaper claims that the Volta GV100 SM includes separate FP32 and INT32 cores, allowing simultaneous execution of FP32 and INT32 operations at full throughput. With 16 FP32 cores per warp scheduler and a scheduler of 32 threads per clock, I don't see how full throughput and 32 threads per clock should be possible without double issue.

@Sebastian Okay, maybe I'm a bit imprecise in calling it double issue. If I interpret the answers here correctly, one instruction is issued per cycle but they take two cycles to be dispatched. So the first 16 threads of one instruction overlap with the second 16 thread half-warp of the previous instruction, assuming both go to different functional units (e.g. one FP32, one INT32)

@Homer512 There were older Nvidia GPU architectures, which actually could issue more than one instruction per cycle. That is a reason, why precision is important here.


At any given time, how many warps are running on each sub-partition? One or multiple?

One or more blocks are mapped onto one SM.  How many warps are running on an SM depends on how many blocks you've started and how big these blocks are.
A deviceBlock<<<1,32>>>() will only occupy a single warp, leaving the other 3 idle.
A deviceBlock<<<200,1024>>>() will map 2048/32 = 64 warps onto a single block.
If you start a very large block, e.g. deviceBlock<<<5000,256>>>() then it will run in batches of max 64 warps per block, one batch after the other.
Every SM-partition has a warp scheduler that issues instructions. Say an sm has 64 warp loads of work, then each partition gets 64/4 = 16 warp loads. The scheduler will schedule these round-robin style, as much as it can. This depends on the latency of instructions and whether the next instruction is waiting on data from previous instructions. If there is a wait, it will skip those and pick an instruction from another of those 16 warp loads.
At any given cycle the partition will only run instructions from the same warp. Even if this means that cores will idle.  It never mixes warps.

Suppose each thread in a warp must add two 64-bit floating point numbers. Since the sub-partition only has 8 FP64 units, we can't do 32 FP64 ops in one clock cycle. What happens in this case? Do the 32 FP64 ops execute in groups of 8 over 4 clock cycles? Can the INT32 and FP32 units execute threads from other warps (or the same warp) while this happens?

A warp has 32 threads. If there are only 8 execution units available (i.e. FP64), then the issuer will issue 4 batches to those cores in 4 consecutive cycles. (1 FP64 instruction is issued in 4 cycles).  The other cores (say the int32 cores) can then (at the same time) execute work from other warps, as long as there is no conflict.
Because there are 16fp32 + 16 int32/fp32 cores, 32 fp32 instructions can be issued per single cycle, but only 16 int32 per single cycle.
Because the GPU does not have a complex pipeline like the CPU does, instructions have a longer latency than CPU instructions. popcount for example takes 7 cycles on Ampere, so whilst waiting for the result (iff there is a dependency) the scheduler will issue instructions from a different warp.
This all depends on available resources
64 warps is a lot of threads (2048), every thread has its own allotment of registers from the 16K x 4 regs available, so 4 x 4=16 regs per thread. If a thread needs more, then fewer warps will be assigned to an SM.
A limited amount of shared memory is available, if the threads use too much up then again fewer warps will be assigned.
The CUDA occupancy calculator (also part of CUDA NSight) will show you the details.
Resources
If you want to program CUDA, you'll need to learn to read like a lawyer, because NVidia writes its documentation in pretty dense language.
The Ampere tuning guide https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/ampere-tuning-guide/index.html
For some more info into how the SMs work and have changed over time, see:
https://medium.com/computing-systems-and-hardware-for-emerging/nvidia-gpus-story-0c7f86afa9a8

You should make more clear that a single instruction is issued per cycle per partition. And a batch does occupy the scheduler for just one cycle, but the execution units for longer. And that due to pipelining instructions overlap anyway. Longer pipeline does not mean less complex, often rather the opposite.

No, a single instruction is NOT issued per cycle. Only for fp32 is that true. But int32 instructions take 2 cycles to get issued.

I meant a single new instruction is scheduled per cycle, but for some instructions it takes more than one cycle to issue it.

What’s the difference between scheduling and issuing an instruction?

@Sebastian, different warps in the same partition can and do execute different instructions. I regularly have different warps execute different code parts on the same block.

@TheProofIsTrivium I am not sure about the exact correct terminology, but as far as I understand: The scheduler of Volta and later architectures each cycle selects one ready active non-blocked warp, for which the pipelines / execution units are free to receive new work. Afterwards over one to several cycles the work is issued to execution units. But already in the next cycle afterwards (with possibly still work being issued) the next warp is selected or scheduled. So during continuous issuing of other lanes to the FP64 unit, another warp is sent to FP32, etc.

@Johan Yes, did I say otherwise? Different warps (or in some sense even different threads within one warp) have different program counters. But each cycle for each SM partition only one warp is selected (and within the warp only lanes with the same value of the program counter).

The first paragraph is really confusing. (a) "...will only occupy a single warp, leaving the other 3 idle." I think you mean will leave 3 of the 4 SM sub-partitions/warps schedulers idle assuming there are no concurrent grids running. (b) "A deviceBlock<<<200,1024>>>() will map 2048/32 = 64 warps onto a single block." The thread block size (or CTA) is 1024 threads. I think you mean to say will result in in 2 thread blocks (CTAs) per SM assuming the GPU (1) supports 64 warps per SM, (2) has <= 100 SMs (or some may only get 1 CTA, and (3) there is not a different occupancy limiter.
